# What are integers $a$ and $b$ if $a\sqrt2 + \sqrt3=0$? And its generalisation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

What are the integers $a$ and $b$ if $a\sqrt2 + b\sqrt3 = 0$?

I suppose answer should be $(a, b) = (0, 0)$. But I am unable to justify it.

**Generalisation:** What are integers $a_i$'s if
$$
a_1\sqrt{p_1} + a_2\sqrt{p_2} + \cdots + a_n\sqrt{p_n} = 0,
$$
where $p_i$'s are distinct primes?

In fact, if we replace prime $p_i$'s with any other distinct positive integers that are not perfect squares, would the values of $a_i$'s be same? And why?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show that $\sqrt{2/3}$ is irrational?  That is the same question.  Use "unique prime factorization" in your proof.  Do the case $a\sqrt2 + b\sqrt3$ before attempting the generalization.

Comment: For the generalization to those that are not perfect squares, it is not true. Consider 2 and 8.